# JavaScript: Unable to read all elements from innerHTML content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read the elements in an innerHTML of a div, but it seems that alternate elements are being read.

Code Block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var tdiv=document.createElement("div");
       tdiv.innerHTML="<span>a1</span><span>a2</span><span>a3</span><span>a4</span><span>a5</span>";

       var cn=tdiv.getElementsByTagName("*");
       var len=cn.length;

       console.log("length: "+len);
       console.log("tdiv len: "+tdiv.getElementsByTagName("*").length);

       for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
          if(cn[i]){
             console.log(i+": "+cn[i].nodeName+": "+cn[i].tagName);
             document.body.appendChild(cn[i]);
          }
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:
a1a3a5

**Note:** a2 and a4 are missing.
I have tried using both `childNodes` and `getElementsByTagName("*")` in all the browsers, IE, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari and I see the same behavior.

When I add a white space between all the spans then all the elements are being read. Is this an expected behavior ? If so, why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned item is a live [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You are appending them to the `body` element, so the NodeList is shrinking with each iteration of the `for` loop. This is what causes it to appear like it's arbitrarily skipping elements.

Try...

```
while (cn.length) {
    cn[0] && document.body.appendChild(cn[0]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHE9N/).

> When I add a white space between all the spans then all the elements are being read. Is this an expected behavior ? If so, why ?

Yes, it's expected. It just means instead of skipping the `span` elements, it's skipping the text nodes introduced by the spaces. Never rely on this - it's terribly fragile.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the code by adding i-- and len-- in the for loop and now every element is being appended to body. Thanks again.!!